# Can't add folder for photo album lockscreen

Tags: windows-10, dropbox, lock-screen

I am trying to create a slideshow of images inside my Dropbox folder and it wont allow me to from the lock screen's settings menu.

I select a Dropbox folder containing all my pics (stored in the C drive BTW) and I get an error saying this:

> The photo album folder isn't supported because of its location, Please choose another folder

Am not sure why it's like this?

any suggestions?

Comment: Where exactly in C: is your Dropbox folder located?

Comment: Its in C:\Users\jrich\dropbox

Comment: That folder is locked down so only your user can access it, that could be your problem.  Try moving your DropBox folder to someplace more public (like say `c:\dropbox`), and once moved, ensure the folder (and files within) is set to allow all users (and the SYSTEM user) to have read access.  Then try adding it again. :)

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem with Google Drive. Same error. Then it 'worked' when I put a slightly different version of the same path. 
Make sure you start with C:\ and then drill down to the folder. 
C:\Users\%username%\
I was just picking the folder path in the left-hand navigation, and for some reason it was not working. 
YMMV.

(And as the prev. poster mentioned, you probably need to make sure the folder is permissioned for access by SYSTEM)

Comment: it's a bug, still present as of Windows 10 build 1703 - if you select a folder it gives this error, if you type in the full path and click select then it works.

Answer (score 3):

The top answer did not work for me, but creating a symlink did.

```
mklink /d c:\photos H:\Dropbox\Photos
```

produces:
symbolic link created for c:\photos <<===>> H:\Dropbox\Photos

Now I can select 'add folder' and go to c:\photos and it works great.

Comment: a p-link junction works the same for anyone else interested

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, drill down from any drive root, i.e. C: ,D: etc
However select but do not open the folder containing your images.
Works every time for me wherever the folder is on any of my connected drives.
Been struggling with this since win 10 came out.